# symfony flush form -- handleRequest($request)

Tags: symfony

I need to flush my form but doesn't work. - symfony 3
Is it because of handleRequest($request) ?

Thanks

```
public function livraisonAction(Request $request) {
    $client = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
    $entity = new ClientsAdresses();
    $form = $this->createForm(ClientsAdressesType::class, $entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity->setClient($client);
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('gba_livraison'));
    }

    return $this->render('GbaBundle:Default:panier/layout/livraison.html.twig', array('client' => $client, 'form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be nice if you could provide more detailed information about what exactly you expecting and how your code actually behaves. Do you get any error when trying to handle your form? What

```
$form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()
```

actually returns? You can add else block to your if statement, or use help of

```
\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump()
```

function to get some debugging info and place it into your question. Unfortunately, it is difficult to say something depending only on code that you provided.

Comment: Than, maybe you got  $form->isSubmitted() or $form->isValid() equal to false, and code inside if is never executed. Could you check this?